# Desktop threat analysis tool for Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, malware

I'm looking for a free threat analysis tool - something similar to Any.Run, but it can be desktop app, and must run on Windows 10 x64. 
Any.Run is great, but free option offers only Windows 7 32-bit.